# How to set up a service account for Google Apps API

Tags: google-apps, google-api-java-client

Inorder to manage google apps using API, iam working with admin-cmdline-sample client project, which i downloaded from admin sdk.
Now i am able to connect to the Google apps cloud and manage user features.
The problem that i am facing now is that in the process of authorization code flow to get the access token,
iam getting redirected to the login page if the emailId that i passed in the code is not already there in the credential store.
so is there any mechanism in which i can pass the password in the client code itself so that i wont be redirected to the login page.
I found some related post, which recommend to setup service account.
I tried that as mentioned in "https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#serviceaccounts", but i am not able to find generate certificate and download private key links.
Currently iam using a free subscription plan,is there any alternative way to generate certificate and download private key for free subscribers or is it possible for paid subscribers only

Answer (score 1):

I hope this can help you.

1. You can create a **Service Account** with a free subscription or a paid subscriber.
2. Log in with your Google Account.
3. [Visit the Google developer console. (click here)](https://cloud.google.com/console/project)
4. Create a new project.

When your project is created:

1. Click on the "APIs" tab.
2. Turn on the apis that you need.

After that, you will see something like this picture.
Click on the **"Create new client ID"** buttton and choose **"service account"**.
After that, your private key (.p12 file) will be downloaded and you will have:

- A Client ID
- An Email Adress
- A Public key fingerprint

You can generate new Keys and download a JSON file.

[image: Creating a service account]

You can read more information about the **Google developer console** [here](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/)

Comment: thanks...i got the private key now, but still i am not able to pass the password for authorization through the client code. For the first time if i pass the emailID of the admin through the client side application it is getting redirected to a Google login page. Is it possible to do this authorisation through the code itself

Comment: You can manage your users in your own app created. But remember you have to use an "admin" account.
If you want to do that, take a look in the Admin SDK page: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/

If you want to manage contacts, visit: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

I don't know what are you trying :)